# Yunqa DiRegExpr - Case insensitive match for Cyrillic text

Tags: delphi

The (?i) token in [Yunqa DiRegExpr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgGvP.png) is used to make a match case insensitive but it doesn't seem to work when using Cyrillic text.  For example:

```
\P{Cyrillic}(?i)ново
```

should match the uppercased `Ново` but it does not.  Is there a a way to make this work?

Using the DiRegEx Workbench application we see:

[image]

My code uses :

```
 if ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?i)') or 
    ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?is)') or 
    ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?si)') then 
      rexp.CompileOptions := [coCaseLess];
```

Comment: This is the English language StackOverflow -> see : http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It is important to know which version of delphi you are using and which version of `DiRegExpr`.  Showing complete code that demonstrates the problem is also important.  Most likely this is confusion between Ansi and Unicode encoded strings.  Without seeing the code you are using, however, it is difficult to offer assistance.  See : [mcve]  (or : [на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @J...: He or she did write in English, right?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis My edit.

Comment: @J...: Ah, ok, I see it now.

Comment: it is Delphi XE3 + DiRegEx 8.33

Comment: @Akella: that's good to know, but does not present a [mcve]. Just edit your question with such an example.

Comment: print screen http://prntscr.com/c8ieoq

Comment: No please edit the question. You should spend some time at the [help] so you know how this site works.

Comment: @J... the workbench is pre-compiled exe AFAIR

Comment: Here is compiled EXE + sources:
https://mega.nz/#!fwpmHaSZ!60X6cLuZvyb0PQf7PVF-Kn8_7g_dLGrcyk_ns075KV4

Comment: Delphi code:

if ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?i)') or ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?is)') or ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?si)') then
      rexp.CompileOptions := [coCaseLess];

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, but we can't see any of the settings OP used to get this null result.  The added code gives us the right clue.

Comment: @Akella225  If you have new information to add you should [edit] your question instead of leaving it as a comment.  I've updated your question with the code you have added.  Attaching full source code in a link is not useful - you should be able to reduce your problem to something that can be easily tested and included in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UTF8 encoded Unicode strings you must use the `[coUtf8]` (`PCRE_UTF8`) compile option.  The match succeeds with this setting.

ie:

```
 rexp.CompileOptions := rexp.CompileOptions + [coUtf8];
```

To see the result you'll need a unicode font intalled in the console, but here is an example program that demonstrates this.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Windows, DISystemCompat, DIUtils, DIRegEx;
var
  RegEx: TDIRegEx16;
  matched : string;
begin
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  RegEx := TDIPerlRegEx16.Create(nil);
  try
    { comment out line below to replicate problem }
    RegEx.CompileOptions := [coUtf8];
    RegEx.SetSubjectStr('Ново');
    RegEx.CompileMatchPatternStr('(?i)ново');
    if RegEx.Match(0) > 0 then
      repeat
        matched := RegEx.MatchedStr;
        WriteLn('Matched: ', UTF8Encode(matched));
      until RegEx.MatchNext < 0
    else
      WriteLn('No match.');
  finally
    RegEx.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

You'll note that by including `(?i)` in the pattern you do not need to include `[coCaseLess]` in the compile options (since you also specify it in the match explicitly).

If you do want to use the compile option instead you can omit `(?i)` from the pattern and just do this instead, which also works :

```
 RegEx.CompileOptions := [coCaseLess, coUtf8];
 RegEx.SetSubjectStr('Ново');
 RegEx.CompileMatchPatternStr('ново');
```